Usage of て + 正解 together?

このお酒美味しいわ　お勧めいただいて正解でしたね

I'm unsure of the nuance of this sentence. Does it mean the recommendation was a spot on or that getting a recommendation was the right think to do? There is no much context except the girl drinking at the beginning of the scene.

でしあ is supposed to be でした?

Re the question title, I don't think the point here is really about the use of て-form, but about the actual verb.

Does it mean the recommendation was a spot on or that getting a recommendation was the right think to do?

I would take it as the latter, or else that it doesn't really matter.
いただいて is the te-form of [頂]{いただ}く, as in the expression いただくます. It's the humble form of もらう, so it can certainly mean that getting (receiving) the recommendation was correct. But since the context clearly involves お酒を飲むこと, it would also make sense to interpret this as "it was right to drink what was recommended".
I don't know that the distinction you're trying to draw really makes a difference. (Perhaps you imagine a situation where someone else ordered for the table?) But if the goal were to focus on the recommendation itself, simply お勧めは正解でしたね makes more sense to me. Politeness wouldn't require inserting a verb (the お prefix is already there); it just requires using the appropriate ones. By process of elimination, I infer an intent to highlight the fact that the recommendation was asked for and received.

+1 but I think "to receive the recommendation" is the only practical interpretation of this お勧めいただく. It's unlikely to be taken as "to drink the recommended ones".
